# Threejs/WebGL export canvas as image of size

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl

I have a canvas that a user can draw on and am trying to export the canvas as image (or read the raw data) in a certain size.

My canvas is in portrait mode (300x500), the underlying original image is 400x400. When I'm using canvas.toDataURL or context.getPixel, my results are always 300x150, as this seems to be the default value for the drawingbuffer size in webgl. I've tried to change those values, but to no avail.

I'm using three.js WebGLRenderer.

Is there any way I can export the canvas/drawings in the right dimensions and size?

Here a short part of my code to illustrate the problem:

CSS:

```
.canvas
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #352a87;
}
```

JS:

```
var c1 = $("#mainCanvas").get(0);
renderer =THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: c1, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
// adding scene and draw on the canvas {omitted}

//later
ar context = $('#mainCanvas').get(0).getContext('experimental-webgl');
var pixels = new Uint8Array(context.drawingBufferWidth * 
context.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
context.readPixels(
    0,
    0,
    context.drawingBufferWidth,
    context.drawingBufferHeight,
    context.RGBA,
    context.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pixels);
```

The problem is that conext.drawingBufferWidth is 300 and context.drawingBufferHeight is 150 instead of the 400x400 that I would need.

I know I never set it to be 400x400, but I wouldn't know how/where is the best place to do so.

Comment: It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: I've added the relevant parts of the code

Comment: Turns out I just need to add the lines c1.height = 400; and c1.width=400; before creating the renderer. I could've sworn I've tried that.

Comment: As you found out, your canvas needs explicit `width` and `height` attributes (not just in CSS). You can also set this via the renderer: `renderer.setSize(w, h);` Just know that some browsers don't like it if you change the size of an element before it is inserted into the DOM.